# Necessary condition for convergence of Riemann integrals

Tags: analysis

For integrals of the form $\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)| dx$, is it necessary that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ = 0 for the integral to converge?

Comment: Yes! Can you see why?

Comment: Yes.  (nine characters added).

Comment: I've been trying to prove it, but I cannot find a rigorous proof. It would be helpful if someone can give a hint how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary. Think about a positive function whose graph is made by an infinite amount of triangles of divergent height and infinitesimal bases. For example for each integer $n$ create a triangle of height $n$ and base $2/n^3$ such that $\int_0^\infty f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$.

**Edit:** This should be the visual idea:
[image]

Comment: How do I show that f is Riemann integrable?

Comment: You can use the geometrical idea of the integral as the area under the graph: in this case you have to sum the areas of an infinite amount of triangles and you get a convergent series.

Comment: Which program did you use to plot the graph? It looks very nice.

Comment: @See-Woo Lee It's Geogebra (https://www.geogebra.org): I just drew manually the triangles to give an idea because writing down the analytical expression would be a suicide.